# Does the run count, or is it considered a force-out

Tags: rules, baseball

**Scenario:** Bases loaded, two out. A ground ball is hit to third base.
The runner from third crosses home plate before the runner from second is tagged out on their way to third base.
Does the run count?

Comment: There is no need to tag any runner. Touching any base (in this case, third) will force an out, ending the half-inning. Assuming the 3rd baseman doesn't error, the run will not count.

Answer (score 0):

There is a force out at third because the bases are loaded. It doesn't matter if the runner on second is tagged or if third base is tagged, there is a force out at third, therefore the run does not count.

Comment: Do you have a source? My reading of the rule (from the linked question) leads me to believe that the run would count since the force out is not taken.

Comment: the bases are loaded. There is a force at any base. Because there is a force, it is not a timing play.

Comment: That is the part that I wanted a source on. Is it still considered a force out even if the runner is tagged instead of the base?